# Meaning and usage of "rife with uncertainty"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of "**rife with uncertainty"** and where it can be used?

I search the meaning but I cannot find desirable answers. Moreover, is it possible to use the "rife with" + (some other words)?

Here is an example that I faced with:

> That means upcoming holiday gatherings, weddings, parties and even just casual hangouts with friends are **rife with uncertainty**.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary.com has a very good explanation for this.

In sum, if something is "rife", that means there is a lot of it. When you use "rife with" it means that something is prevalent or abounding.  Yes, you can use it with anything as long as it makes sense, but I have found that it is usually used with abstract concepts like, "the office was rife with discontent" or "The country was rife with joy". Something like "America is rife with cellphones" has a sort of playful or silly connotation in my opinion.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rife?s=t